# Different output based on radio input selection PHP

Tags: php, post, radio-button, isset

I have this nice little radio button function that spits out a form. It's a nicer version of a radio button called a switch field, and it works great! However, my "if (isset())" blocks aren't working and I've tried using the radio IDs, the names, the values...nothing is working. Did a var_dump on $_POST right after the function call and it is empty. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

My intention is to treat this radio selection buttons as "tabs" for the page. I want each selection to display something different. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
radioSelection();

if (isset ($_POST['radioSel']) && $_POST['radioSel'] == 'sys' ){
   ...do something with systems...
}

if (isset ($_POST['radioSel']) && $_POST['radioSel'] == 'equip' ){
   ...do something with equipment...
}

function radioSelection(){
    echo '  <div class="switch-field"><form method="post" onchange="onSelectChange(this)">
                <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radioSel" value="sys" checked/>
                    <label for="radio1">Systems</label>
                <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radioSel" value="equip" />
                    <label for="radio2">Equipment</label>
                <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radioSel" value="user" />
                    <label for="radio3">Users</label></form>
            </div>';
}
```

Comment: `$_POST` is only set when you submit the form, not when you first open the page.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally left that out. I edited code in question.  My form is submitted on selection change.

Comment: Show the `onSelectChange()` function, it might not be submitting it correctly.

Comment: Use the Network tab of Developer Tools to see what's being sent when the form is submitted.